# Getting wrong number of rows after dropping row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

After I drop a specific row in a Pandas dataframe with:
`df = df.drop([rowNumber])` I no longer can get the correct number of rows with `len(df.index)`.
I have tried resetting the index with both `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` and `df.index = range(len(df))`. When I go to debug the program, the index definitely is the correct length, but when using `len(df.index)` it will give me a higher number than the actual dataframe. What is causing this? How can I solve it? Or is there a better way of determining number of rows in a dataframe?

Comment: you only need `len(df)` but `len(df.index)` without reset_index should be work...

Comment: `df=df.drop([rowNumber])` followed by `len(df.index)` should work. You try it once again.

Answer (score 0):

df.index should have a start and stop. which you can access with df.index.start and df.index.stop

```
df.index                                                                                                                                                            
#RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

df.index.stop
#3
```

If these are not at 0 and the stop not at the end, this could be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to use the `inplace` option, if set to true it apply changes to the dataframe itself else it will return a new dataframe.
I used it after using the dropna and it worked correctly
`df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)`

[this](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-reset-index/) article explain different option for `reset_index()`